# Is it possible to upload data from javascript to the server?

Tags: javascript, php, upload

I have a piece of javascript code that generates a `.jpeg` through an editor built on canvas. I want to transfer the `.jpeg` to the server and save the file on the server. So far I managed to send a file from the client to the server with an HTML POST. But I can't seem to get it done from within javascript.

Since javascript can't access the client's file system, how can you get data from javascript to the server?

I used the code beneath to send a file from the client to the server.

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
  <div >
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload" id="but_upload">
  </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery("#but_upload").click(function() {
       var fd = new FormData();
       var files = jQuery('#file')[0].files[0];
       fd.append('file', files);

       jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:1234/wordpress/wpcontent/themes/twentyseventeen/upload.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: fd,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(response){
             if(response != 0){
                 alert('file uploaded');
                }
                 else{
                   alert('file not uploaded');
                }
            },
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't this work ? Are you getting some error ?

Comment: Normal approach with wordpress ajax is to add an action and use wp-admin ajax url as outlined in wp docs

Comment: It does work when sending a file from the clients drive. Not when sending a variable from within js.

Answer (score 0):

you have to send images in a multiparted request to server(send file in body), search `how to create a upload route in server`